# How to find a file whose size is less than 10 MB?

Tags: linux, unix, find

I need to find a file in my current directory whose size should be less than or equal to 10 MB.

`ls -lh` gives me the file size of each file but not sure how to find the files whose size are less than or equal to 10 MB.

```
host@407d:t1_snapshot$ ls -lth
```

Is there any way I can do that? I am running ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 10):

`find . -type f -size -10485760 -ls` run in your current directory or you can do

`find /etc/home/user/stuff -type f -size -10485760 -ls` using a path

so, my format is basically

`find path` of `-type f` (file) with `-size` of less than (`-`)`10485760`(10MB in B) and `-ls` to make it pretty for you. Per Dennis' suggestion adding `-maxdepth 1` would prevent recursing into subdirs, if that is what you desire

Comment: `-maxdepth 1` avoids recursing into subdirectories, if that's unwanted.

Comment: @dennis good addition.

Comment: Also, by default `-size` takes 512-byte blocks as its argument. For 10 MB, use `-size -10000000c` or `-$((10**7))c`. For 10 MiB, just use `-size -10M`.

Answer (score 2):

The inquirer is asking two different questions: 1) how to locate files with a particular filename whose size is less than 10 MB ("...a file whose size is...") and 2) how to locate all files whose sizes are less than 10 MB ("...the files whose size are..."). And so far the answerers above have only answered number 2.

Locate all files called filename.txt (particular filename) less than 500 kB :

```
find /path/subpath -type f -size -500k -name filename.txt
```

Locate all files whose size is less than 500 kB :

```
find /path/subpath -type f -size -500k -ls
```